# vectorize sample function: sample from sample population and create list of sampled vectors

Tags: r, vectorization, apply, sample

I'm trying to vectorize sample: sample from same population several times, each time different sample size.

I have a vector `a = c(boo = 5, foo=7)`, and `b =LETTERS[1:10]`.

I want to create a list, with values sampled from b, where sampling size is determined by values of a.

I've tried `mapply(sample, b, size = a)` but it doesn't work...

Comment: Try `mapply(function(x,y) sample(x, size=y), list(b), a)`

Comment: Well, even if I sample from b, `mapply(function(x,y) sample(x, y), b, a)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Refresh the screen :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mapply(function(x,y) sample(x, size=y), list(b), a)
[[1]]
[1] "D" "F" "H" "A" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "C" "D" "B" "I" "F" "G" "E"
```

`mapply` takes the first element of each of the objects provided in the `...` argument and applies the function over them.

We must use `list(b)` so that it will be used as one single element. If we just enter `b` there, the function would try `b[1]` instead and so on.

We can imagine each iteration like so:

```
#mapply form
mapply(myfunc, x, y)

#first time
myfunc(x[1], y[1])

#second time
myfunc(x[2], y[2])

#and so on
```

Comment: I wonder, is there a way to use name of the vector as names of the list items? Of course, I can use `names(list_a_b) <- names(a)`

Comment: Yes that is the best way.